# Using javascript to update <embed> parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I've been recently trying to implement a flash application, which at some point needs to be embedded via html. It looks something like>

```
<embed src=".." quality=".."  ... and at some point  FlashVars="&firstparam&secondparam..."
```

What I am trying to do is implement a dropdown, which would when pressed change that FlashVars parameter so the app shows something different. I've tried with

```
document.getoElementByID().FlashVars="new parameters"
```

but it doesn't work (it works perfectly for highlited default parameters such as src, height, width...)

I've also tried to write whole embed part again with javascript snippet,  but it also didn't work. How is this done in javascript? I'm a beginner in this field so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why your code didn't work, you should understand what's `flashvars` parameter and how it's working.

Adobe said about that [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html), for example :

> The FlashVars parameter of the HTML <OBJECT> tag sends variables into the top level of a SWF file when it loads in a web browser. The <OBJECT> tag is used to add SWF files to HTML pages. The <EMBED> tag can also be used, but is older and now obsolete.

So here we can understand that those variables are loaded when the SWF is loaded and that's why even if you've changed the `flashvars` parameter, that will do nothing, absolutely nothing to that loaded SWF which should be loaded again to get them (variables) applied.

So to do that, take this simple example :

**HTML :**

```
<div id='swf_container'>
    <embed id='swf_object' src='swf.swf' flashvars='id=1' />
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
// change the flashvars attribute
var swf_object = document.getElementById('swf_object');
    swf_object.setAttribute('flashvars', 'id=2');

var swf_container = document.getElementById('swf_container');

var inner_html = swf_container.innerHTML;

// reload the swf object
swf_container.innerHTML = '';
swf_container.innerHTML = inner_html;
```

This manner is, of course, working but maybe it's not a good idea to reload the SWF object everytime we need it to do something, and that's why we have [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to communicate between the SWF and JavaScript.

---

So in the case where you've access to the ActionScript code to create that SWF, you can use `ExternalInterface` to call any function in your SWF when it's already loaded.

For that, take this example :

**ActionScript :**

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
{
    // registers an AS function to be called from JS
    ExternalInterface.addCallback('from_JS_to_AS', from_JS);
}

function from_JS(id:int) : void 
{
    // use the id sent by JS
}
```

**JavaScript :**

```
var swf_object = document.getElementById('swf_object');
    swf_object.from_JS_to_AS(1234);
```

... and don't forget to use [`swfobject`](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to avoid some browsers compatibility and to be sure that you establish the communication between your ActionScript side and the JavaScript one ...

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you. I gave up a little as I thought this was some trivial thing to solve with Jquery  - but it didn't work. You explained this thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this :

```
$('embed') // targets the embed tag in the DOM
```

`.attr("attribute-name","attribute-value");`

Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/1a6mwb13/2/

Comment: Thank you very much..This jQuery really helped.